# How can I force a T4 Text Template to stop executing?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, t4

I just wrote a T4 Text Template with an infinite output loop. (Oops.) When I saved the .tt file, it froze Visual Studio solid, and I had to force the entire IDE process closed. Is there any more elegant way of stopping an executing T4 Text Template?

Answer (score 0):

Other than to build a significant amount of infrastructure into your template (or a base class for it), I'm afraid not, no.

Answer (score 0):

right click the text template, click on properties, look for "Custom Tool" option it has a value of "TextTemplatingFileGenerator", you just have to remove it. (make it an empty string)